# How can I highlight words dynamically in QTextEdit using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to create a Text Matcher application using Python. I want to highlight the unmatched words dynamically in the QTextEdit. I am using eventFilter to match the text.

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if obj is self.textEdit_2 and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Space:
            self.check()
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Backspace:
            self.textEdit_2.insertPlainText("")
            return True
    return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

Here is the text matching code:

```
def check(self):
    var=self.textEdit.toPlainText().split()
    var2=self.textEdit_2.toPlainText().split()
    i=len(var2)-1
    if var[i]!=var2[i]:
        sw=var2.pop()
        self.textEdit_2.clear()
        self.textEdit_2.append(' '.join(var2)+' '+f"<span style='background-color: yellow;'>{sw}</p>")
```

I need to highlight the words in textedit_2 which do not match in textEdit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install a `filterObj` to your `QTextEdit` widget (Doc: [QObject::installEventFilter()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter)) inside the `__init__()` builder of your `MainWindow.

Now, your code will work fine, except for one thing: when you write more words in the second `TextEdit`, the program will no recognize the error.

Doing some "improvements" to your code (Just to test, if you cando it better, perfect) your `__init__()` will look like this:

```py
def __init__(self):
    ...# some code to build your app
    self.textEdit_2.installEventFilter(self) ## <<---HERE IS THE CRUCIAL PART
    self.good = True
```

, your `eventFilter()` will look like this:

```py
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if obj is self.textEdit_2 and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Space:
            self.check()
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Backspace:
            self.textEdit_2.clear()
            self.good = True
            return True
        else:
            if not self.good:
                var2 = self.textEdit_2.toPlainText().split()
                sw = var2.pop()
                self.textEdit_2.clear()
                self.textEdit_2.append(' '.join(var2)+' '+f"<span style='background-color: yellow;'>{sw}</p>")
                self.good = False           
    return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

And, finally, your `check()` will look like this:

```py
def check(self):
    var = self.textEdit.toPlainText().split()
    var2 = self.textEdit_2.toPlainText().split()
    j = len(var)-1
    i = len(var2)-1
    if i-j <= 0:
        if var[i] != var2[i]:
            sw = var2.pop()
            self.textEdit_2.clear()
            self.textEdit_2.append(' '.join(var2)+' '+f"<span style='background-color: yellow;'>{sw}</p>")
            self.good = False
    elif i-j == 1:
        sw = var2.pop()
        self.textEdit_2.clear()
        self.textEdit_2.append(' '.join(var2)+' '+f"<span style='background-color: yellow;'>{sw}</p>")
        self.good = False
```

The `self.good` is just a bool variable that I made to let your App know if the current text has errors or not. Here is how it look when I run a simple App I did to test if it works:

[image]

### Edit

### To find all the errors in the second `QTextEdit`

Now, you commented that you need to find all the errors in `textEdit_2`. So I did these:

- Delete the `self.good` bool variable I made before.
- Change a bit the `eventFilter()` function
- Rewrite your `check()` function.

The code is here:

```py
def __init__(self):
    ...# some code to build your app
    self.textEdit_2.installEventFilter(self)

def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if obj is self.textEdit_2 and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Space:
            self.check()
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Backspace:
            self.textEdit_2.clear()
            return True        
    return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

def check(self):
    var_1 = self.textEdit.toPlainText().split()
    var_2 = self.textEdit_2.toPlainText().split()
    len_1 = len(var_1)
    len_2 = len(var_2)
    self.textEdit_2.clear()
    text = []
    for it in range(len_2):
        if it < len_1:
            if var_1[it] == var_2[it]:
                text += [var_2[it]]
            else:
                text += ["<span style='background-color: yellow;'>"+var_2[it]+"</span>"]
        else:
            text += ["<span style='background-color: yellow;'>"+var_2[it]+"</span>"]
    text = ' '.join(text)
    self.textEdit_2.append(text)
```

And It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What's the point of `self.textEdit_2.setStyleSheet("")`? Also, the `else` in the event filter can probably just be an `elif`.

Comment: Thanks for the improvements. But there is some issue with the code. Once an error is encountered no new word can be written as the text gets merged with previous error. I need to find all the errors in the textedit_2.

Comment: @musicamante Yes, you are right, both of the things you pointed are residual from other tests that I did in order to have a "decent result" and now are pointless. I will polish my answer

Comment: @Aditya Joshi You didn't ask: "How to compare two sentences and find errors?", Your question was "how can I highlight words dynamically in QTextEdit using Python?". Anyway, I will try to do something that can help you, but take into consideration what I said.

Comment: @AdityaJoshi Now it works, check it and tell me if you find errors.

Comment: Now I have one more problem. When I press Space the text in both the textEdit scrolls to last page. But this happens only when I am using event filter. Can you tell what I can do to stop this from happening?

Comment: @AdityaJoshi Please provide a reproducible example to review it.

Comment: @ AlejandroCondori I have added the script in another question. Please check my question....https://stackoverflow.com/q/65932756/15049965